# my images array is empty when I pass student to actions in redux but it is working in postman

Tags: reactjs, django, redux, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add image files to images array using React but I am getting an empty images array. My backend is written in Django. It is working fine when Im using postman to insert image files but I am getting an empty array when using react.
[image: Postman insert of student]

AddNewStudent.js file

```
const AddNewStudent = () => {

  const [Name, setName]= useState('')
  const [Enrollment_No, setEnrollmentNo]= useState('')
  const [Registration_No, setRegistrationNo]= useState('')
  const [Semester, setSemester]= useState('')
  const [Year, setYear]= useState('')
  const [Course_Name, setCourseName]= useState('')
  const [Course_Code, setCourseCode]= useState('')
  const [studentImages, setStudentImages]= useState([])

  const dispatch= useDispatch()

  const submitForm= (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const images=[]
    for (let image of studentImages){
      images.push({
        image
      })
    }
    console.log(images)
    
    const student={
      Name,
      Enrollment_No,
      Registration_No,
      Semester,
      Year,
      Course_Name,
      Course_Code, 
      images
      
    }
    
    
    console.log(student)
    dispatch(addStudent(student))

    


  }

  const handleStudentImages = (e) => {
    setStudentImages([
      ...studentImages,
      e.target.files[0]

    ])
  }




    return (
        <CCard>
            <CCardHeader>
              Add New Student
              
            </CCardHeader>
            <CCardBody>
              <CForm action="" method="post" onSubmit={submitForm}>
                <CFormGroup>
                  <CLabel htmlFor="nf-name">Name</CLabel>
                  <CInput type="text" id="nf-name" name="nf-name" placeholder="Name" autoComplete="name" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}/>
                  
                </CFormGroup>
                <CFormGroup row className="my-0">
                  <CCol xs="6">
                    <CFormGroup>
                    <CLabel htmlFor="nf-enrollmentno">Enrollment No</CLabel>
                  <CInput type="text" id="nf-enrollmentno" name="nf-enrollmentno" placeholder="Enrollment Number" autoComplete="enrollment_no" onChange={(e) => setEnrollmentNo(e.target.value)}/>
                  
                    </CFormGroup>
                    </CCol>
                    <CCol xs="6">
                    <CFormGroup>
                  <CLabel htmlFor="nf-registrationno">Registration No</CLabel>
                  <CInput type="text" id="nf-registrationno" name="nf-registrationno" placeholder="Registration Number" autoComplete="registration_no" onChange={(e) => setRegistrationNo(e.target.value)}/>
                  
                </CFormGroup>

                    </CCol>
                    </CFormGroup>
                   
            
                  

               
                <CFormGroup row className="my-0">
                <CCol xs="6">
                  <CFormGroup>
                  <CLabel htmlFor="select">Select Semester</CLabel>
                  <CSelect custom name="select" id="select" onChange={(e) => setSemester(e.target.value)}>
                      <option value="0">Please select</option>
                      <option value="1">Semester 1</option>
                      <option value="2">Semester 2</option>
                      <option value="3">Semester 3</option>
                      <option value="4">Semester 4</option>
                      <option value="5">Semester 5</option>
                      <option value="6">Semester 6</option>
                      <option value="7">Semester 7</option>
                      <option value="8">Semester 8</option>
                    </CSelect>
                  </CFormGroup>
                </CCol>
                <CCol xs="6">
                <CFormGroup>
                  <CLabel htmlFor="select">Select Year</CLabel>
                  <CSelect custom name="select" id="select" onChange={(e) => setYear(e.target.value)}>
                      <option value="0">Please select</option>
                      <option value="Fall 2020">Fall 2020</option>
                      <option value="Spring 2021">Spring 2021</option>
                      <option value="Fall 2021">Fall 2021</option>
                      <option value="Spring 2022">Spring 2022</option>
                    
                    </CSelect>
                  </CFormGroup>
                  </CCol>
                  </CFormGroup>
                  
                  
                  


              <CFormGroup row className="my-0">
                <CCol xs="6">
                <CFormGroup>
                  <CLabel htmlFor="select">Select Course Name</CLabel>
                  <CSelect custom name="select" id="select" onChange={(e) => setCourseName(e.target.value)}>
                      <option value="0">Please select</option>
                      <option value="DCN">DCN</option>
                      <option value="OOP">OOP</option>
                      <option value="DBMS">DBMS</option>
                      <option value="DSA">DSA</option>
                    
                    </CSelect>
                  </CFormGroup>
                </CCol>
                <CCol xs="6">
                <CFormGroup>
                  <CLabel htmlFor="select">Select Course Code</CLabel>
                  <CSelect custom name="select" id="select" onChange={(e) => setCourseCode(e.target.value)}>
                      <option value="0">Please select</option>
                      <option value="D1-101">D1-101</option>
                      <option value="ST-203">ST-203</option>
                      <option value="AD-567">AD-567</option>
                      <option value="TU-689">TU-689</option>
                    
                    </CSelect>
                  </CFormGroup>
                </CCol>
              </CFormGroup>
              <CFormGroup row>
                  <CCol md="3">
                    <CLabel>Add Images</CLabel>
                  </CCol>
                  <CCol xs="12" md="9">
                    <CInputFile 
                      id="file-multiple-input" 
                      name="file-multiple-input" 
                      multiple
                      custom
                      onChange={handleStudentImages}
                      
                    />
                    <CLabel htmlFor="file-multiple-input" variant="custom-file">
                    {
                        studentImages.length > 0 ? studentImages.map(img => {
                          return(
                            <span style={{paddingRight: 10}}>{img.name}</span>

                          )
                        }) : 'Add files...'
                    }
                    </CLabel>
                   
                   
                    
                  </CCol>
                </CFormGroup>
                <CCardFooter>
              <CButton type="submit" size="sm" color="primary"><CIcon name="cil-scrubber" /> Submit</CButton> <CButton type="reset" size="sm" color="danger"><CIcon name="cil-ban" /> Reset</CButton>
            </CCardFooter>
             
                
           
               
              </CForm>
            </CCardBody>
          
          </CCard>
    )
}

export default AddNewStudent

actions student.js 
export const addStudent = (form) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
     
        dispatch({
            type: studentConstants.ADD_STUDENTS_REQUEST
        })

        try{
            const res= await axios.post(`/student/`, {
                ...form
            })
            console.log(res.data)

        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error.response.data)
        }

    

        

    }
}
```

[image: console printed student]I get the images as files, when I print student but when I pass student to actions, the images array is empty

[image: when I pass studentto actions images array is empty]

Comment: I think you may need to JSON stringify your `form` data object in your `addStudent` action creator.

Comment: hi, when I do that Im getting errors.{Name: Array(1), Enrollment_No: Array(1), Registration_No: Array(1), Year: Array(1), Course_Name: Array(1), …}
Course_Code: ["This field is required."]
Course_Name: ["This field is required."]
Enrollment_No: ["This field is required."]
Name: ["This field is required."]
Registration_No: ["This field is required."]
Year: ["This field is required."]
__proto__: Object e

Comment: Bummer, sorry. Have you verified your `studentImages` state is updated? You can use the react-dev-tools for this. When the action is dispatched what is the value of the `form` object? Is `form.images` what you expect it to be? Have you checked the network tab to see that your POST request is correct? Have you compared *that* request against the one made in Postman?

Comment: You might need to set `multipart/form-data` as content-type (header on the request)

Comment: hey, I set the headers "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x" but it is returning me the same errors

Comment: Thank you so much @NadiaChibrikova. It is finally working I set the headers to match the content type in my postman request and it works like a charm now!

Comment: Happy to hear it! And thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

so I finally got it working.
what I did was I changed the student object into form data

```
    const form= new FormData();
    form.append('Name', Name)
    form.append('Enrollment_No', Enrollment_No);
    form.append('Registration_No',  Registration_No);
    form.append('Semester', Semester);
    form.append('Year', Year);
    form.append('Course_Name', Course_Name);
    form.append('Course_Code', Course_Code);
   
    
    for (let image of studentImages){

 
      
      form.append(`image_${image.name}`, image)
    }
```

and then added content hedaers to the addStudent action

```
  const headers= {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>"
            
        }

        try{
            const res= await axios.post(`/student/`, form, { headers: headers })
            console.log(res.data)

        }
```

and it works!